# EditText with automatic return

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText in my Android app. When I write something on it I don´t have the enter on my Keyboard and when the cursor goes to the final of the line doesn´t jump to the line below automatically. Which are the properties to change this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question, it works

```
edittxt.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
edittxt.setMinLines(minLines);
edittxt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
edittxt.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
edittxt.setSingleLine(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write these two lines in  edit text xml

android:singleLine="false"

android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"